# How to change Blob's default mime-type in model, so it deserializes as image/png?

Tags: angular, typescript, mime-types

I have a TypeScript model:

```
export class Picture{
    public id : number;
    public name : string;
    public data: Blob;
}
```

I get it from my Spring WebService in this form:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "first_image.png",
    "data": "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"
},
```

When it gets deserialized, it becomes:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...
```

How do I change that so it becomes `image/png`? I suppose I have to specify it somewhere, because you can't change the mime-type of an existing blob.

Comment: How are you currently de-serializing it?

Comment: Using HttpClient's get<T>